# How to check Relations in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I was wondering how to check all files/classes/controllers involved in my Model

Old Scheme looks like:
`user -> billing` (user has only one billing)

New Scheme:
`user -> billing` (user has more than one bill)

Is there a way to automate checking of all files/classes/controllers instead of manually.
Thank's in advance!

Comment: `user -> billing` gives you the billing rows. What exactly do you mean by _check_ ?

Comment: TDD, in this way you can write tests to ensure the usage and implementation of your feature work in the way you expect. Without I believe you are left with your own self QAing process.

Answer (score 0):

This is where your testing takes in consideration, but if you haven't started testing one way is to use an IDE, like phpstorm, this gives you an idea where are your models implemented in that way.

But moving forward testing would be the best place to check if something has been changed in your models.